# CSS para SASS converter ou não?

Tags: css, sass

Tenho vários arquivos em css, estou na duvida se reescrevo ele em sass para poder dar uma manutenção melhor no futuro ou não, será que é realmente vantajoso?

Comment: Amigo sempre é bom utilizar sass por questões de alterações futuras e agilidade, mas você tem que colocar na balança e analisar se vale a pena o trabalho.

Comment: Entendi, vou analisar, são muitos arquivos mais talvez seja vantagem no futuro.

Comment: Não vale a pena. Primeiro que vejo como trabalho desnecessário, depois que na verdade pode dificultar a manutenção, afinal nem todo dev trabalha com SASS, SCSS etc... então vc limita muito as pessoas que mexem no código, além do mais vc tem que ter um compilador, e a pessoa pode não ter esse compilado de forma ágil. Eu não sei não, só vejo desvantagens... Mas cada um cada um. Achei sua pergunta basada em opiniões...

Comment: Eu uso gulp para copilar e fazer outras automações de qualquer forma o dev tem que ter uma experiencia a mais para dar manutenção, o sass só seria mais uma tarefa para o gulp fazer.

Answer (score 0):

É um bocado relativo e vai gerar muitas opiniões contraditórias, até porque um dos apetos positivos sobre o `SASS` é que não precisas converter `CSS` em `SASS`, uma vez que o `SASS` é uma extensão do `CSS`. Por outro lado, o `SASS`, dá-te coisas diferentes.

De seguida, apresento alguns **benefícios** na utilização do `SASS`:

**- Compatível com o CSS:**

Se tens bases de `CSS`, perceber e desenvolver `SASS` será pacífico. O SASS apresenta duas sintaxes diferentes, o `SASS` em si e o `SCSS`, que é o mais utilizado. A sintaxe `SCSS` é compatível com `CSS`, isso implica que se renomeares o ficheiro .css em .scss, terás o ficheiro em SCSS sem qualquer problema.

**- Uso de variáveis**:

Um dos grandes benefícios de usar o `SASS` é a capacidade de usar variáveis. Por exemplo:

```
$blue: #004BB4;
```

Depois de criar a variável, pode usá-la onde quiser:

```
h1 {
  color: $blue;
}
```

***- Nested Syntax***:

Por outras palavras, permite "aninhar" elementos `HTML` utilizando **selectores** `CSS`. Por exemplo:

```
.navbar {
  color: $blue;
}
```

**- Uso de *Mixins***:

O uso de ***Mixins*** entra em ação quando tens blocos de código repetidos. Por exemplo:

```
@mixin set-font( $family: 'Ubuntu' , $weight: 400 , $style: normal ) {
  font-family: $family , 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-style: $style;
  font-weight: $weight;
}
```

Depois de ter definido o ***Mixin***, podes utilizá-lo onde quiser, usando o **@include**:

```
h1 {
  @include set-font;
  color: $blue;
}
```

Se precisares fazer alguma atualização ao ***Mixin***, basta passar os parâmetros dentro da chamada **@include**.

```
h1.callout {
  @include set-font('Nunito',600);
  color: $azul;
}
```

**- Maior comunidade e boa documentção:**

Uma das grandes vantagens é sem dúvida a [Documentção oficial](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/index.html) e [Comunidades](http://sass-lang.com/community).

---

Em suma, há muitos mais benefícios no uso dos pré-processadores `CSS` como o `SASS`, porque são sempre uma mais valia, visto que ampliam os recursos básicos de `CSS`, fornecendo um conjunto de funcionalidades poderosas que elevarão sua produtividade. Para além dos benefícios mencionados acima, o SASS permite-te fazer uso de **herança**, **funções**, **diretivas de controlo** e **expressões** como `if ()`, `for ()` ou `while ()`, **tipos de dados**, **interpolação**, etc.

Se estas a procurar de fazer o [*refactoring*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refatora%C3%A7%C3%A3o) do `CSS` em `SASS` bem estruturado, basta utilizar algumas ferramentas de conversão, como por exemplo este [aqui](http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/).